# pull/float right not working in Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have an angular app and I am using bootstrap and angular material to design it. I want to create a header to the app and I have 2 buttons in the header, one on the left and the other suppose to be on the right.

here is my component

```
<mat-toolbar>
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <button mat-raised-button>
      <fa name="cog"></fa>
    </button>
    <button mat-raised-button class="float-right">
      <fa name="refresh"></fa>
    </button>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Note: I've tried both `pull-right` and `float-right`.

to add bootstrap I installed bootstrap module and added it to style.css

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

in addition I added ng-bootsrap module to my app and imported it
in my app component

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    AngularFontAwesomeModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

however nothing seem to work and pull my button right, any ideas?

Comment: create Stackblitz for that or at least jsfiddle

Comment: I am unfamiliar with these concept,can you elaborate?
do you mean that I'll create a tab which you can run (like in the answer below)

Comment: Cab you use google ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Bootstrap-4` removed `pull-*` classes.

> Added .float-{sm,md,lg,xl}-{left,right,none} classes for responsive floats and removed .pull-left and .pull-right since they’re redundant to .float-left and .float-right. - [Booststrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/migration/#utilities)

---

There are a couple of ways to align the last button on the right side.

1. Use `d-flex` and `justify-content-between` classes on the container of the buttons.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
  <button class="btn btn-primary">
      Cog
    </button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">
      Refresh
    </button>
</div>
```

2. Use `ml-auto` on the last button.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex ">
  <button class="btn btn-primary">
      Cog
    </button>
  <button class=" btn btn-primary ml-auto">
      Refresh
    </button>
</div>
```

3. Use `float-right` on the last `button`. But it only works, if its parent is not `flex` and there is enough space.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button class="btn btn-primary">
 Cog
</button>
<button class=" btn btn-primary float-right">
  Refresh
</button>
```

## Update

Check the codes in this [pen - codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vrNPgL).

Comment: thanks for the answer, just one questions 
how did you create this tab in your answer that allows me to run your code?

Comment: Read this post on [`stackoverflow-blog`](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). But the icon is changed. Instead of pencil, it is `<>` now.

Comment: I can but part of my question is about angular,should I change it to simple html?

Comment: You should add `angular cdn` first and then add the `angular` code in the `JS` section of them.